# Identify only application windows from EnumDesktopWindows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

This is my very first C++ application. I have absolutely no experience in C++ or Windows application programming so any feedback/help is appreciated. Please let me know if I am making any mistakes or not following best practices in my code.

I am trying to write a C++ program that replicates the behaviour of the WIN + D
keyboard shortcut, but only affects the windows on the monitor with the mouse.

Inspite of checking `IsWindowVisible()` and `IsIconic()` there are some system windows that get minimized and maximized, resulting in weird glitches like:

- All icons from the desktop get minimized, and a gray bar appears
- A blank instance of Microsoft Edge opens
- The Windows Settings app appears out of nowhere

The code to minimize the windows:

```cpp
static std::stack<HWND> minimizedWindowPointers;
Monitors monitors;
RECT activeMonitorRect;

static BOOL CALLBACK windowEnumerator(HWND w, LPARAM l){
    if(!IsWindowVisible(w) || IsIconic(w) || getWindowTitle(w).size() == 0) return true;

    RECT r;
    GetWindowRect(w, &r);
    if(doRectsIntersect(r, activeMonitorRect)){
        SendMessage(w, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);
        minimizedWindowPointers.push(w);
    }

    return true;
}
void minimizeWindowsOnActiveMoniter(){
    if(monitors.getRectOfMonitorWithPointer(&activeMonitorRect)) return;

    EnumDesktopWindows(NULL, windowEnumerator, NULL);

    areWindowsMinimized = true;
}
void maximizeWindowsOnActiveMoniter(){
    HWND w;
    for(int i = minimizedWindowPointers.size(); i > 0; i--){
        w = minimizedWindowPointers.top();
        minimizedWindowPointers.pop();
        if(IsIconic(w)){
            SendMessage(w, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);
            std::wcout << "MAXIMIZING: " << getWindowTitle(w) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    areWindowsMinimized = false;
}
```

I am running Windows 10 Pro, with Visual Studio 19 Preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetWindowLong can get the window flags with GWL_STYLE. Check for WS_CAPTION and WS_MINIMIZEBOX. I would also check for WS_VISIBLE again for good measure.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlonga): 

This function has been superseded by the `GetWindowLongPtr` function.

Comment: @KartikSoneji: "If you are retrieving a pointer or a handle", which we are not.

Comment: Thank You! That fixed the problem. This is the first time programming in C++, and I have absolutely no idea of what the sentence "If you are retrieving a pointer or a handle" means.